# Communication between 2 Docker Composes using Network results in "SequelizeHostNotFoundError"

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 2 docker composes , one is Infrastructures and the second is Appplications.

I need a direct line from **Appplications => Infrastructures** , to run migrations on a Postresql container in `Appplications` docker ,and it (Infrastructures) must be listening before make requests from `Appplications`.

**Infrastructures :**

```
version: "3"

networks:
  shared_network:
    driver: bridge

services:

  # PostgreSQL
  my_postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      .... // ENVS
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:5432"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 15
    networks:
      - shared_network
      
      
      ... more infrastructures
```

**Applications :**

```
version: "3"

networks:
  shared_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  # Employees Service
  emps:    
    build:
      context: ./emps_service
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - shared_network
      
      
      
      
      
      ... More apps
```

I'm using **default.yaml** for Sequelize :

```
... more definitions 


sequelize:
  database: some_random_db
  host: my_postgres
  user: xxxx
  password: yyyy
  dialect: postgres  
  seederStorage: "sequelize"
```

and when I run `docker-compose up` , twice , first for the **Infrastructures** , and only once it's up another `docker-compose up` for the **Applications** , I get :

```
**SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND my_postgres**
```

How can we fix this ?

Comment: Is this on a different folder? if you define the network external, it has to work.

Comment: @JinnaBalu: Yes ,on different folders , each `docker-compose` with its own files on different folder

Comment: With different `docker-compose.yml` files in different directories, Compose treats these as two totally separate projects, and there are actually two different `shared_network`s, one in each project.  The linked question describes how to connect them together (by declaring one of the networks as `external: true`).

Comment: @DavidMaze: I've checked out the links you've provided even before posting my question , and still they do not work.
I'll post another question with the same details so you'll be able to see for yourself.

Thanks